# Mysql optimized query to manage time slot foreach date to display sorted appointment

Tags: php, mysql

I have to show appointment for a user in order as first show today's appointment in increasing order of time_slot then tomorrow appointment in same increasing order of time_slot and so on.

Table structure -

appointment_table

```
id  time_slot   date       book_by
1     5        3/7/2014     abc
2     2        3/7/2014     def
3     4        4/7/2014     ghi
```

View as -

1. Appointment by **def** at {time mapped for slot 2} on 3/7/2014
2. Appointment by **abc** at {time mapped for slot 5} on 3/7/2014
3. Appointment by **ghi** at {time mapped for slot 4} on 4/7/2014

In simple but long way I can do this by first getting all booked appointment dates and then foreach date get the booked slots in increasing order and finally merge all result.

But can any one help me with a single or more optimized way to do the same thing.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort by 2 columns, first date, then time_slot

```
SELECT `columns` FROM `table` ORDER BY date ASC, time_slot ASC
```